# The CoverImagePath field is required. but field is not used in view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am uploading an image and trying to save image path in database, but I get an error.

[image]

and `modelState.valid` is null

[image]

Please suggest a way to save image path to the database.

Comment: See this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71359898/iformfile-upload-image-asp-net-core-mvc-is-showing-null-value-always

Comment: **WHAT** error ? Remember: we cannot see and read your screen, nor can we read your mind - you need to **SHOW US** the relevant info in order for us to be able to help ...

Comment: it is showing CoverImagePath is required